# Error on uploading on video from Node JS server net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, amazon-web-services

I am using

> angular HttpClient

to upload assets(Images,mp3,mp4,pdf).

All assets upload successfully on my

> DEV server

but on

> Production server (AWS server)

All assets upload except VIDEO (.mp4) . I don't find the reason .

Getting error on console Requesting

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe due to a timeout on the server? Or max size for upload

Comment: @David No , I am able to upload 1 mb Image but not 1 MB vdo

Comment: Is it just with chrome? And are you testing with https / http2?

Comment: no , this error is on Firefox as well . issue is with both Http and HttpClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for all sizes of m4 ? If this issue is only related to the larger file size please check with your web server configuration for nginx set size in this way.
client_max_body_size 200M;